# Event on data changing in bindingsource

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I have DataGridView and BindingSource with DataSet. When I filled dataset using datatable adapter I would like some event triggered when each row has added to dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The RowsAdded event is fired everytime a row is added to the DataGridView.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Edit: 
Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you meant you wanted an event fired when rows where added to the dgv.